# Where to change the reference for the files and which are the files have to upload?

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I Have created a SPFx hello world webpart it's running good in the local work bench and i have created the package and tested but it getting error, 
and finally i found that it's because of  the **internalModuleBaseUrls** property in the **loaderConfig** entry still refers to your **local computer**:

```
"internalModuleBaseUrls": [
"https://`your-local-machine-name`:4321/"
```

]

how can i run the application without the local server ? and where to upload the required files and which are they ?

please am waiting for your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in detail in the [Deploy your SharePoint client-side web part to a CDN](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/deploy-web-part-to-cdn) article. While the article uses deploying the web part files to an Azure Blob Storage account as an example, you can use any server to host your files, as long as they are accessible over https.

The URL pointing to where your files are stored is defined in the **./config/write-manifests.json** file. After changing the URL you should build and package your solution in release mode using the following commands:

```
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```